# js regex replace multiple words

Tags: javascript

I need to replace ${conferance name} with ABC, ${conference day} with Monday in the following sentence.
Could some one help me with the regex.

```
var text = "<td>${conference name}</td><td>${conference day}</td>"

var list = ["${conferance name}", "${conference day}" ]

for (var j = 1; j < list.length; j++) {
            //Extracting the col name
            var colName  =   list[j].split("${");
            colName = colName.split("}")[0];
            //Replacing the col name
            text = text.replace(new RegExp('\\$\\{' + colName + '\\}', 'g'), "ABC");

        }
```

The above code repalces fine if i have ${conference_name}, but it fails when i have a space in between.

The list is a dynamic array. And the Replace texts are also dynamic. I just simulated them as objects here for fitting them in the Regex Statement.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The above code is invalid syntax.

Comment: Pardon me for the syntax errors. It could be a typo. But this is teh logic that i use in a bigger chunk of code.

Comment: Also, there is no syntax error on the Regex, which is the core answer i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that lets you parameterize the replacements explicitly:

```javascript
function doReplace(repl, str) {
  var regexStr = Object.keys(repl).map(function(s) {
    return s.replace(/([^\w\s])/g, '\\$1');
  }).join('|');
  return str.replace(new RegExp(regexStr, 'g'), function(m) {
    return repl[m];//it changed to "repl"  
  });
}

var replacements = {
  "${conference name}": "ABC",
  "${conference day}": "Monday"
};

doReplace(replacements, text) // => "<td>ABC</td><td>Monday</td>"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for a regex, since you know the exact string to search for.

```
var str = "<td>${conference name}</td><td>${conference day}</td>";
var list = {
  "conference name":"ABC",
  "conference day":"Monday"
};
var i;
for( i in list) {
  if( list.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    str = str.replace("${"+i+"}",list[i]);
  }
}
```

The only catch is if you might have more than one of the placeholders in your search string, but in that case the innermost code can be:

```
do {
  oldstr = str;
  str = str.replace("${"+i+"}",list[i]);
} while(oldstr != str);
```

Comment: `str.replace("${" + i + "}", list[i]);`

Comment: this would repalce only one instance. I went in for the regex, coz i need to replace all instaces in the text.

Comment: @Raghav Use this: `str.replace(new RegExp("${" + i + "}", "g"), list[i]);`.

Comment: sorry @Vision this is not replacing any text

Comment: Edited to fix the problem where I forgot the keywords were enclosed in `${...}` :D

Comment: you're still missing the "g" (cf. @VisioN 's comment)

Comment: @Christophe that's for regexes, and the whole point of my answer is that you don't need them. I gave the alternative required to replace all instances.

Comment: @Kolink why would you avoid regexes and prefer do...while loops?

Comment: Because for regexes to work you have to make sure you escape every single symbol with regex meaning. Here, though, any string is fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var str = "<td>${conference name}</td><td>${conference day}</td>";
    var list = ["${conference name}", "${conference day}" ];
    var listResult = ["ABC", "Monday" ];
```

## Generic model

See it working http://jsbin.com/atehun/6/watch

Construct `str, list, listResult` as shown in above example.

```
function genericReplace(str, list, listResult) {    

    var escape = function(text) {
        return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    };
    
    var escList = [];
    for (var i=0; i < list.length; i++) {
      escList.push( escape(list[i]) );
    }
    
    var regEx = new RegExp(escList.join('|'), "g");

    return str.replace(regEx, function(word) {
      return listResult[list.indexOf(word)];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can u pls do the replace with list[i]? list being string array. list[i] = "${conference name}"

Comment: Edited! Also see the fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
var r = {
        "conference name": "ABC",
        "conference day" : "Monday"
    },
    reg = new RegExp("\\$\\{" + Object.keys(r).join("\\}|\\$\\{") + "\\}", "g"),
    str = "<td>${conference name}</td><td>${conference day}</td>";

str = str.replace(reg, function(v) {
    return r[v.substring(2, v.length - 1)];
});
```